# Google Maps KML layer change polygon color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have a site with a KML layer outlining some areas with color codes.
Each color is based on a computed score - so if the higher the score is the darker the color is.

My issue is i want to let the user decide how to compute the score, and thus i need to generate the KML layer on the fly but the KML file is about 2-3Mb and takes a while to load.

Is there any way to split the polygon data in the KML file and the styles and then just update the styles?  that way i could have a static KML file with the polygon data and another dynamic file handling the colors.

Can i do that?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference - https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport

Comment: I fail to see how linking the documentation helps me, i have read it in great detail but have not found a way to do what i describe - which is to load only part of the KML data to minimize the page load. I probably need some out of the box solution that i hope someone inhere can direct me towards :-)

Comment: There is the geoxml3 library (for manipulating kml) which might be of help?
http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution. You cannot separate a style tag from the placemark tag.  Also - for speed - I hope you are using KMZ, not KML.  The KML will compress by 80% or more.